# Reading from and printing contents of IFF file works on Windows, but not Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, file, netbeans

I'm having a little cross-platform issue with Java.

I'm using the following code

```
String get = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Iff Location?");
String output = new Scanner(new File(get)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
System.out.println(output);
```

to read from a .IFF file and print the contents to the console.

In Windows it runs perfectly, however in Linux it's resulting in the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /media/44CC4D34CC4D2212/TreList/datatables/buff/buff.iff  (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
at iffreader.IffReader.main(IffReader.java:23)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Are you certain the file is at `/media/44CC4D34CC4D2212/TreList/datatables/buff/buff.iff`?

Comment: 100% sure that that's the path. I even tried dragging and dropping the file into the JOPtionPane and erasing the file:// part.

Comment: You need to go to the command line and enter something like `wc -c /media/44CC4D34CC4D2212/TreList/datatables/buff/buff.iff`, then you will see ....

Comment: Ty Ingo... this is what that command returned

Comment: It looks like there's extra whitespace after the file name in the error message: `"buff.iff "` Double check the name for trailing space...

Comment: 366658 /media/44CC4D34CC4D2212/TreList/datatables/buff/buff.iff

Comment: There's no trailing whitespace either :| quadruple checked.

Comment: What happens if you check the permissions with `ls -l`?

Comment: Also, can you insert `System.out.println(new File(get).getAbsolutePath());` before the line where you make use your scanner to verify what path Java is looking at?

Comment: -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    366658 Mar 29 22:19 buff.iff

Comment: @thegrinner it returned /root/Desktop/buff.iff